# Android Download Manager checks file space

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I have two questions on download manager in android:

I am using this code

```
DownloadManager mgr = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

                Uri downloadUri = Uri.parse(myURL);
                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
                        downloadUri);
```

Question 1: Will download manager check if space exists? 
Question 2: If Internet is down, will download manager start downloading files immediately after internet is back online?

It would be great if somebody could help me with above questions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked and DownloadManager does download when device comes back online; even if app has been closed.
Don't know about the space issue.

You should call mgr.enqueue(request); at end.